# AutoCompleteTextView on selectiong item 3 warnings appears

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

This is the declaration of AutoCompleteTextView.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState==null){
            mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchPartyViewModel.class);
        }
        View root=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order, container, false);
        initMessege=(TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.initMessege);
        newOrderPartyProgressBar=(ProgressBar)root.findViewById(R.id.newOrderPartyProgressBar);
        newProductDetailView=(ConstraintLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.newProductDetailView);
        listView=(LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        productSearchAutoCompleteTextView=(AutoCompleteTextView)root.findViewById(R.id.productSearchAutoCompleteTextView);
        newOrderParty=(AutoCompleteTextView)root.findViewById(R.id.newOrderParty);
        GetRetailList();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,retailerList);
        newOrderParty.setAdapter(adapter);
        newOrderParty.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("choosen",retailerList.get(position));
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

when a item is selected from the drop down list the following erros appears

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

and add   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

```
`autocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
  position, long id) {
    //... your stuff
  }
 })`
```

Comment: The warnings are still produced even after these changes.

Comment: check and try this i implement this in my code and its working ... and get string from parent

Answer (score 0):

write below code in your AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener()

=================================================================================

autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            autoComplete.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    autoComplete.showDropDown();
                }
            },100);
            autoComplete.setText(autoComplete.getText().toString());
            autoComplete.setSelection(autoComplete.getText().length());

```
    }
});
```

=========================================================================================
This will give you hint for your question, change according to your need and adapter data.